# AppDomainSetup could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, orleans

Fiddling around Microsoft Orleans.
This is the silo I've written from the tutorial, I get wierd error the "AppDomainSetup couldn't be found" although I can see it in the docs under System.

Searching google leads to nowhere...

```
class Program
{

    static SiloHost siloHost;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain hostDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("OrleansHost", null,
            new AppDomainSetup()
            {
                AppDomainInitializer = InitSilo
            });

        DoSomeClientWork();

        Console.WriteLine("Orleans Silo is running.\nPress Enter to terminate...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        hostDomain.DoCallBack(ShutdownSilo);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AppDomainSetup` is not listed in the official .NET Core 2.0 API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=AppDomainSetup&view=netcore-2.0

Where do you see it? Could you be looking at .NET Framework docs by any chance?

Also, please note that even though `AppDomain.CreateDomain` is part of .NET Standard API, [it will throw `PlatformNotSupporteException`](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#is-appdomain-part-of-net-standard) on many implementations, such as .NET Core. `AppDomain` is not really a cross-platform concept. Parts of it are implemented and supported but the concept of separate application domains is not cross platform and **not** supported in .NET Core/.NET Standard.

Comment: Thanks. do you by any chance know how could i get this to work with .net-core?

Comment: There is a separate version of orleans for .NET Core. They have an example here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/Samples/HelloWorld.NetCore/src/SiloHost/Program.cs. It looks like the entire startup sequence is very different.

Comment: If `AppDomain.CreateDomain` is not cross platform compatible what would be? Is there something else that replaces it?

Comment: AppDomain's "domains" are not a cross-platform concept. There's no real cross-platform equivalent.